# Python way to add a space character before this part: "3/8"?

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping

How can i change my code to get the informations in the correct format?
When i export it into csv i get a date format, i want to holding this 3/8, and i think the easiest way if i put a space before (and after?) this character / .

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import re
 
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
f = open('0910000511.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

datatable=[]
stop = 0
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" ):
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            if 'modul' in data.text:
                stop = 1
                break
        datatable.append(temp_data)
        if stop == 1:
            break
    if stop == 1:
        break 

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

And this is the example in notepad :

```js
" ";" ";"    Hatályos: 2013.12.30. (CK - 2014.01.09.) - ..."
" ";"7/2";"HU 4080 Hajdúnánás, Kossuth utca 12-14.
Változás időpontja: 2013.12.30.
Bejegyzés kelte: 2013.12.19.
```

Comment: It's difficult to suggest what you should do because there is no sample data and no code that deals with writing a CSV or excel file. Add sample data and relevant code to your question.

Comment: I edited my question.